# how to get transaction history from blocks via web3?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have a private chain now and I want to query the transaction histories.I know that web3 has provide those methods **web3.eth.blockNumber**/**web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount**/**web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock**. So I can get the transactions history by get latest blocknumber(suppose it's n). Range from n to 0 to call web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(i), then get transactions by web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock. but it's just time wasting and inefficient.
so I'm wondering how can I get transaction histories from blocks efficient via web3 or rpc or anyway?

Answer (score 2):

For each block you can pass `true` as the second parameter to [`getBlock`:](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock)

```
web3.eth.getBlock(blockHashOrBlockNumber [, returnTransactionObjects] [, callback])
```

Comment: thxs, it somehow helps, but I think it's still a little of low efficiency. I mean, if I have a contract and a map(mapping (address => User) public users;), I can get user info immediately nomatter which block I stored the user info. Anyway, thxs for your answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

This code will give `Transactions` details by Block Number.

```
async function GetBlocks(BlockNumber){
    Block =await web3.eth.getBlock(BlockNumber)
    Block.transactions.forEach(async(transaction) => {
        let t=await web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction)
        console.log(t)
    })
}
GetBlocks(26154210)
```

If you have Array of Blocks. e.g. Blocks=[10000,10001,10002,10003...]. then use a for loop like this:-

```
Blocks.forEach(e => {
    GetBlocks(e)
});
```